# Need help slicing date value

Tags: javascript, node.js

```js
result_database = [
  { id: 1, name: "Tom Riddle", date: "2022-05-16T22:00:00.000Z" },
  { id: 2, name: "Hank Some", date: "2022-05-19T22:00:00.000Z" },
  { id: 3, name: "Family Man", date: "2022-05-17T22:00:00.000Z" },
];
var holiday_date = new Date().toJSON().slice(0, 10);
let holiday_date_remove = result_database.filter(
  (item1) =>
    !result_database.find(
      (item2) =>
        item1.name == item2.name && item2.date.slice(0, 10) == holiday_date
    )
);
const holiday_result = [
  ...new Map(
    holiday_date_remove.map((item) => [JSON.stringify(item.name), item])
  ).values(),
];
console.log(holiday_result);
```

I'm trying to `.slice(0,10)` the date. I get it displayed like this `"2022-05-16T22:00:00.000Z"`, but I need it as `"2022-05-16"`, so I try to `date.slice(0, 10)` it's not working though.

Comment: So surprisingly it does display the correct result whenever someone hits today. So if family man and hank some are absent today it still excludes them which is what i want. It just displays the date weirdly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first map over `result_database` using [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and update the `date` property and then filter the array based on `holiday_date` using [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

```js
const 
  result_database = [
    { id: 1, name: "Tom Riddle", date: "2022-05-16T22:00:00.000Z" },
    { id: 2, name: "Hank Some", date: "2022-05-19T22:00:00.000Z" },
    { id: 3, name: "Family Man", date: "2022-05-17T22:00:00.000Z" },
  ],
  holiday_date = new Date().toJSON().slice(0, 10),
  holiday_date_remove = result_database
    .map((item) => ({ ...item, date: item.date.slice(0, 10) }))
    .filter(({ date }) => date !== holiday_date);

console.log(holiday_date_remove);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const dataDate = '2022-05-17T22:00:00.000Z' 

const date = new Date(dataDate)

date.getDate()  + "-" + (date.getMonth()+1) + "-" + date.getFullYear()

console.log(date)
```

For more information regarding date formats read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Answer (score 0):

You should split by "T" when it's in ISOString format.

`const yourTypeDate = new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0];`

This comparing below is working, it will check if the db date is equal today date, if it's will remove the index, the filter is working.

```js
result_database = [
  { id: 1, name: "Tom Riddle", date: "2022-05-16T22:00:00.000Z" },
  { id: 2, name: "Hank Some", date: "2022-05-19T22:00:00.000Z" },
  { id: 3, name: "Family Man", date: "2022-05-17T22:00:00.000Z" },
];
var holiday_date = new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0];
let holiday_date_remove = result_database.filter(
  (item1) =>
    !result_database.find(
      (item2) => {
        item2.date = item2.date.split('T')[0];
        return ((item1.name == item2.name) && (item2.date.split('T')[0] == holiday_date));
        }
    )
);
const holiday_result = [
  ...new Map(
    holiday_date_remove.map((item) => [JSON.stringify(item.name), item])
  ).values(),
];
console.log(holiday_result);
```